# Extraction of keyless JSON data with jansson

Tags: c, json, parsing, extract

I want to extract values from a JSON file that doesn't have the key descriptor in front of the values but where the values are simply separated by a colon.

This is an example of the kind of input I have:

```
{"out":[[0.2,15],[0.5,3.3],[0.1,46.8]],"in":[[0.6,20.2],[0.04,66.654],[0.0124,1.5]]}
```

I can't use [this](http://jansson.readthedocs.org/en/latest/apiref.html#json_object_key_to_iter) or some similar function as they all need the key, which doesn't exist.
Could you point me to a clean way to do this, preferrably with a function included in [Jansson](https://jansson.readthedocs.org/en/2.5/), if such function exists.
If I have to do it manually I'd be very thankful for a code snippet.

Thanks in advance,

blue_lagoon

Comment: That's an "object" containing arrays of arrays.  Standard JSON stuff -- any JSON parser can handle it.  You access the data as a dictionary/map of arrays/lists -- very straightforward.  (See json.org for info on JSON syntax.)

Comment: (From the C terminology standpoint "out" and "in" are 3x2 arrays.)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, what values is it you can't access? The `0.2`? Couldn't you get `"out"` by key, then `json_array_get()` to access the values by index?

Comment: use `json_object_foreach`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sample

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <jansson.h>

int main(void){
    char text[] = "{\"out\":[[0.2,15],[0.5,3.3],[0.1,46.8]],\"in\":[[0.6,20.2],[0.04,66.654],[0.0124,1.5]]}";
    json_error_t error;
    json_t *root;
    json_t *in, *out, *obj;
    json_t *array, *element;
    double value;
    const char *key;
    int i, j;
    root = json_loads(text, 0, &error);
    if(!root){
        fprintf(stderr, "error : root\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "error : on line %d: %s\n", error.line, error.text);
        exit(1);
    }
    in = json_object_get(root, "in");
    if(!json_is_array(in)){
        printf("NG1\n");
    }
    array = json_array_get(in, 1);
    if(!json_is_array(array)){
        fprintf(stderr,"NG2\n");
    }
    element = json_array_get(array, 1);
    value = json_real_value(element);
    printf("%f\n", value);//66.654000

    out = json_object_get(root, "out");
    array = json_array_get(out, 2);
    json_array_foreach(array, i, element){
        value = json_real_value(element);
        printf("%f ", value);//0.100000 46.800000
    }
    printf("\n");

    json_object_foreach(root, key, obj){
        printf("%s:\n", key);
        json_array_foreach(obj, i, array){
            json_array_foreach(array, j, element){
                value = json_number_value(element);//json_real_value NG for 15 
                printf("%f ", value);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
/*
out:
0.200000 15.000000
0.500000 3.300000
0.100000 46.800000

in:
0.600000 20.200000
0.040000 66.654000
0.012400 1.500000
*/
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's awesome, thanks for the sample code! Works like a charm!

Comment: I've been searching for something like that for quiet some time but 95% of the problems people have related to JSON seem to be with Java on Android.